# LDAP integration with ExactTarget

Tags: marketing-cloud

How to integrate LDAP (IBM Tivoli Directory Server) with ExactTarget?
I have tried to check in ET Wiki but not got any single document. If anyone has integrated LDAP with ET please guide me how to do it or share some related documents.

Comment: What's the use-case?

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple 3rd party LDAP solutions which integrate with ExactTarget. Some of these are

- [OneLogin](https://www.onelogin.com/connector/exacttarget-single-sign-on)
- [Bitium](https://www.bitium.com/exacttarget-email-single-sign-on-sso-provider)
- [FormAssembly](https://help.formassembly.com/help/article/link/340343-ldapactive-directory-authentication)

If you're looking for an ExactTarget API which directly does this, I don't think there's any such API present.

Comment: I am looking for IBM Tivoli Directory Server integration with ET. Do you have any information on this?